# is there any way to send data as response from nio server to io client?

Tags: java, nio, server

I can send data from io client(using just socket not socket channel), but it was not possible to send data from nio server(using socket channel). What is the problem?

Is there a difference between the way to read/write through I/O stream and bytebuffer?

```
public class Server {

    // this is equivalent to the server socket in the non nio world
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;

    // this is the multiplexer which multiplexes the messages received from
    // different clients
    Selector selector;

    public Server() {
        try {

            // get a selector
            selector = Selector.open();

            // get a server socket channel
            serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();

            // we force the socket to be Non-blocking.
            // if it is set to "true" then this socket acts as a normal
            // (blocking) server socket
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

            // port and ip address where the server listens for connections
            InetSocketAddress add = new InetSocketAddress(
                InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9999);

            // bind the server socket to the ip/port
            serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(add);

            // register the serverSocketChannel (for incoming connection events)
            // to the selector.
            // The "SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT" parameter tells the selector that
            // this serverSocketChannel registers
            // itself for incoming (acceptable) connections
            SelectionKey key = serverSocketChannel.register(selector,
                SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
            System.out.println("serverSocketChannel's registered key is : "
                + key.channel().toString());

            System.out.println();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.startListening();
    }

    private void startListening() {

        System.out.println("Server is listening on: "
            + serverSocketChannel.socket().getInetAddress()
                .getHostAddress() + ":"
            + serverSocketChannel.socket().getLocalPort());

        while (true) {
            try {

                // this line blocks until some events has occurred in the
                // underlying socket
                selector.select();

                // get the selected keys set
                Set selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();

                Iterator iterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();

                    iterator.remove();

                    // a client has asked for a new connection
                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        // only ServerSocketsChannels registered for OP_ACCEPT
                        // are excepted to receive an
                        // "acceptable" key

                        System.out.println("Key ready to perform accept() : "
                            + key.channel().toString());

                        // as usual the accept returns the plain socket towards
                        // the client
                        SocketChannel client = serverSocketChannel.accept();

                        // set the client socket to be non blocking
                        client.configureBlocking(false);

                        // register the client socket with the same selector to
                        // which we have registered the
                        // serverSocketChannel
                        client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                        // client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // the client has sent something to be read by this server
                    if (key.isReadable()) {

                        System.out.println("Key ready to perform read() : "
                            + key.channel().toString());

                        // get the underlying socket
                        SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);

                        // read the msg sent by the client
                        client.read(bb);

                        // display the message
                        bb.flip();
                        byte[] array = new byte[bb.limit()];
                        bb.get(array);
                        System.out.println(new String(array));

                        // send the message

                        ByteBuffer bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);

                        String s = "server data";
                        byte[] array1 = new byte[bb1.limit()];
                        array1 = s.getBytes();
                        bb1.put(array1);
                        client.write(bb1);

                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void write() {

    }


}

public class Client {
    static String IP = "192.168.123.105"; // server IP address
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
        IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String msg;
        Socket socket = new Socket(IP, 9999);

        System.out.println("client: complete making socket");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("client: input data to send");

        while (true) {
            // read
            System.out.print(">>>");
            msg = scan.nextLine();

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dou = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dou.writeUTF(msg);

            // write from server

            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
            String remsg = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("client: data from server" + remsg);

            if (remsg.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
                System.out.println("SOCKET END");
                socket.close();
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just register a write selection key. When you receive information, you can't send at the same time, you have to remember what you need to send and wait until the socket is writable.

Comment: @Ordous That's not correct. You can try the send any time. Only if it doesn't complete do you have to go through the `OP_WRITE/isWritable()` path.

Comment: @OP 'Not possible' is not a problem description. You need to state exactly what happened. There is no real question here.

Comment: @EJP But you have to provision for the (likely) possibility. This code doesn't - that might as well be the problem. But since I'm not sure - that was a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Ordous That's what I said. If and only if the write doesn't complete, you have to go through the `OP_WRITE/isWritable()` fandango. But to claim that you can't send while receiving is simpy false, and if you weren't sure about that you should have said so, instead of stating it as a fact. Your comment is wrong and should be deleted.

Comment: @EJP thanks. i couldn't know what the problem is.. so my description was not enough to descrpit my problem. sorry i can't be sure if socket from server goes and client doesn't read or socket from server doesn't go..

Comment: @EJP i tried post results in the way to be read clearly.. it was hard..here is result <<SERVER SIDE RESULT>> 
Server is listening on: 192.168.137.187:9999
Key ready to perform accept() : sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/192.168.137.187:9999]
Key ready to perform read() : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/192.168.137.187:9999 remote=/192.168.137.187:52737]
dsagdsa
<<CLIENT SIDE RESULT>> is connecting. server IP : 192.168.137.187
client: input data to send
>>>dsagdsa
client: data from server

Answer (score -1):

i solved problem!

it was a problem about how to read from inputstream in client

i changed a part of client code

from

```
  InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
        String remsg = din.readUTF();
        System.out.println("client: data from server" + remsg);
```

to

```
ByteBuffer bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);
            byte[] array1 = new byte[bb1.limit()];
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            in.read(array1);
            String remsg=new String(array1);
```

and also added OP_WRITE/isWritable() in server code like this

```
if (key.isReadable()) {

                    System.out.println("Key ready to perform read() : "
                            + key.channel().toString());

                    // get the underlying socket
                    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

                    // read the msg sent by the client
                    client.read(bb);

                    // display the message
                    bb.flip();
                    byte[] array = new byte[bb.limit()];
                    bb.get(array);
                    System.out.println(new String(array));

                    client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);


                    continue;
                }



 if(key.isWritable()){

                    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                      ByteBuffer bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);

                        String s = "server data";
                        byte[] array1 = new byte[bb1.limit()];
                        array1 = s.getBytes();
                        bb1.put(array1);
                        bb1.flip();
                        client.write(bb1);
                    }
```

Comment: `bb1` serves no useful purpose here, and you are ignoring the length returned by `read()`, and the possibility of end of stream. It should be `int count = in.read(array1); if (count > 0) { String remg = new String(array1, 0, count)` ... } etc. And initializing variables when you reassign them in the very next line is pointless and poor practice.

Comment: right. i'm just practicing so there should be useless variables. i'm trying to make this code more simple and i already get rid of lots of things